# redirecting not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a little function to redirect a person to page of search results based on a text value input and the redirect function that I used in Javsacript works fine in IE and Google Chrome but however does not work in fireFox.

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='btnSearchTest']", function () {
//alert('test');


var txtBoxValue = $('#txtSearchGeneral').val();
if (txtBoxValue == "") {
    alert("Please enter a value");
    return false;
}
window.event.returnValue = false;

document.location = "SearchResults.aspx?search=" + txtBoxValue;
```

Any advice perhaps on how to get redirecting done using javascript in firefox

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
   window.location.href = "SearchResults.aspx?search=" + txtBoxValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
window.location.href = "SearchResults.aspx?search=" + txtBoxValue;
```